# mvc parse and display contents of json in a checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am new to mvc and this is my requirement. I am developing a page which should render a text and a checkbox. The checkbox will be checked depending on the T/F value from the database. So I am passing all the necessary data from db to the view as Json object in GetData() method.

```
    namespace ClinicalAdvantage.Web.Controllers.UserAppSettingC
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    using NHibernate.Mapping;

    public class UserAppSettingsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAgg1 agg;

        public UserAppSettingsController(IAgg1 agg) 
        {
                 this.agg = agg;
        }

        #region Public Methods and Operators

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return this.View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            return new JsonNetResult() { Data = this.agg.GetAllUserAppSettings() };
        }

        public ActionResult Save(JObject userAppSettings)
        {
            if (userAppSettings != null)
            {
                this.agg.SaveAllUserAppSettings(userAppSettings);
            }

            return this.Json(new { Status = "Success" });
        }

    #endregion
    }
}

I have once tried returning the same data written as a viewmodel as a result of the index(). I had done something like

  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return this.View(model);
        }

And for this I wrote out the in the corresponding view as 

    @model ClinicalAdvantage.Web.ViewModels.UserAppSettings1.UserAppSettingsViewModel 


<form action="@Url.Action("Save")" method="post">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsM, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50" })
    <!-- Form content goes here -->
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

But for some reason I am not using viewmodel to return data. So the above way of  coding the veiw might not be right. I am not using GetData() to pass data to the front end and I can't really change this.

public ActionResult GetData() { return new JsonNetResult() { Data = this.agg.GetAllUserAppSettings() }; }

But I want to know how to code the front end to parse this json data when I am returning it as result of GetData method as tyype JsonNetResult.. Where will my view be. What should be the code if I want to display a checkbox and save button. The checkbox will be populated based on value returned by json.

This is the json I am returning

{"MaskPatientName":{"enabled":true,"value":false}}

There should be a label called MaskPatienTName
The check box should be checked if value property is true

On click of save butoon the save method in the controller shld be called.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to pass the populated view model to the view in your Index action

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(agg.GetAllUserAppSettings());
}
```

And then your view should look something like this (use the Html helper to create form markup). This assumes that IsM is a property of UserAppSettingsViewModel.

```
@model ClinicalAdvantage.Web.ViewModels.UserAppSettings1.UserAppSettingsViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "UserAppSettings")) {
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsM, new { maxlength = "50", size = "50" })
    <!-- Form content goes here -->
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: Thanks Philm! I get what you said. But for some reason I am not using viewmodel to return data. That was how I did first. But now I really can't change this way of passing data to the front end. Which is as a json using GetData() something like this                                        public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            return new JsonNetResult() { Data = this.agg.GetAllUserAppSettings() };
        }

Comment: so can you pls tel me how to read this from front end. where should I write the view for this?

Comment: Ok, in that case why not use ViewBag to pass data from your action to the view? Don't make it more complicated than it needs to be! At the end of the day, you're only setting the value of a checkbox

Comment: My scenario is not simple as how I posted. I should only be passing data in Save() and would like to debug the Save Action method. I dont have the front end ready to trigger Save action. So with just this code, if I have to debug save method and pass my own jobject as paramter to save without being trigered from front end, how can I do so?